# How to use ebtables inside Docker?

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, ebtables

When I run `/sbin/ebtables --list` in a Ubuntu Docker container, I get the message:

```
root@500790dca629:/core-release-4.8# /sbin/ebtables --list 
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:557 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.43-boot2docker/modules.dep.bin'
The kernel doesn't support the ebtables 'filter' table.
```

How can I enable ebtables in Docker?

Answer (score 2):

By default docker doesn't support this capability. But you can pass below parameter while launching docker container to support Linux capability:

```
--cap-add       Add Linux capabilities
--cap-drop      Drop Linux capabilities
```

For Network capability like iptables, ebtables etc. you have to add `NET_ADMIN` capability like:

```
docker run -it --cap-add=NET_ADMIN ubuntu bash
```

if `ebtables` package not installed then install `ebtables` package in container using command:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install ebtables
```

then list ebtables:

```
/sbin/ebtables --list 
Bridge table: filter

Bridge chain: INPUT, entries: 0, policy: ACCEPT

Bridge chain: FORWARD, entries: 0, policy: ACCEPT

Bridge chain: OUTPUT, entries: 0, policy: ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding mount helped me

```
    cap_add:
        - 'ALL'
    volumes:
        - '/dev:/dev'
        - '/lib/modules:/lib/modules'
```

root@linuxbridge-agent:/# ls /lib/modules
5.4.0-26-generic  5.4.0-37-generic  5.4.0-39-generic  5.4.0-40-generic